# mp3 from email to player

Tags: email, music-player

I want to download an mp3 from email and listen to it through the google music player.  I currently do it through yahoo mail and jelly bean 4.2.2.  However after downloading I have to turn off and back on phone for it to show in player.  Closing the player and restarting player does not get it to recognise the newly downloaded file.

There must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is. All that has to be done is having the *Media Scanner* run and update the index. Turning the device off and on again triggers this, but (as you said) is not a very convenient way. Unmounting/mounting the SD card would trigger it as well (and can be done via *Settings→Storage*) -- already a little better, but still not very user-friendly.

The most easy way would be to have an app like e.g. [Rescan Media](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.addz.mediascanner) taking care for it. [Rescan SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uberullu.rescansd) might be even more convenient, as it offers a widget. Just tap it, wait for the scan to finish, and your MP3 file should be visible from your music players.

Comment: sweet.  Im using nexus so there is no sd card.  Rather than install to test - would you know if the rescan sd will also rescan internal GB through widget?

Comment: AFAIK all it does is trigger the *Media Scanner*, which in turn should take care for all locations. Hence the name is a little misleading. Just give it a try (what could go wrong?), and report back so we know for sure next time :)

Comment: just tried out the rescan media.  I had to close play, do rescan, and then open play, and there it was. It closes itself so dont see how a widget would improve my life further than the icon.  It works.  Sweet.  Saved so much time....

Comment: @Jon I fully agree! It's just that I had not tested either, so I wanted to give you both options :)

Answer (score 0):

I switched to HTC one (m7) and the included HTC player updates its files automatically.  It also has a nice circle round the play button saying how far into the track it currently is.  Google should play catchup.